# elasticsearch date range to get a date range between today and yesterday

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch and I'm trying to get a report from **ANY SECOND PAST 10:am** the previous day **to 10:am the present-day**. Please assist, thanks.

I have tried this :

```
  "@timestamp":{
    "gte": "now-1d/d+10h",
    "lt": "now/d+10h"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the mapping of the `@timestamp` field according to the format of data you are using. You can refer to this [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) to know more about date field type.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-05-04 10:11:51"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-05-04 09:11:51"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-05-05 09:11:51"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2022-05-05 09:11:51"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-1d/d+10h",
        "lt": "now/d+10h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67392888",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2021-05-05 09:11:51"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67392888",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2021-05-04 10:11:51"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Rowls did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)

Comment: @Rowls if the answer helped you resolve your issue then please don't forget to accept the answer as well :-)

Comment: Your answer helped me @ESCoder  PS. I found this answer by adding "within the last 1 year" to my Google search. Seems Elastic Search has changed a lot over the years...

Comment: @Adam glad I could help you ;-)